# How "Alongside Windows" option works?

Tags: partitioning, windows-7, uefi

I have Windows 7.
Two partition with ntfs, one of them installed with windows 7.
Also there's 100 gb unallocated area in my hard drive.

So If i choose "alongside windows" is it using my unallocated area or resizing other partitions?

PS: I tried advanced partitioning but Windows 7 gave "efi failure" on grub. I readed and tried most of solutions but none of them worked.

PSS: I'm new on Linux.

Answer (score 0):

It creates a partition in your unallocated space and use it as `/`.

edit: And about your advanced partitioning, you can choose any partition you want, to format and select as `/` and also if you like, create a `swap` partition. May be you'd better edit your question and tell us about your problem with Win7.